# Designing hotel room schema

Tags: database-design

I tried to give it a chance without thinking much and this is what I came up with:

```
Room
----

| ID | No.  | Type    | Price   | Beds | Hotel| Size  | TV          | Minibar | Bathroom | Images | Booked |
| ---|------|---------|---------|----- | ---  | ----  | --------    | -----   | ------   | -----  | -----  |
| 1  | 101  | Deluxe  | 5000.00 | 2    | A    | 31m^2 | 32inch(hdtv)| yes     | Private  |
| 2  | 102  | Economy | 4000.00 | 1    | A    | 25m^2 | 30inch(flat)| no      |
| 1  | 103  | Deluxe  | 5000.00 | 1    | A    | 31m^2 |             | yes     |
| 2  | 104  | Suite   | 9000.00 | 2    | A    | 50m^2 | 70inch(LED) | yes     |
```

I see that there are many facilities which belongs to a room and I tried to create a column for each but it started looking hairy. Also, `Hotel` column will be a many2one field as well as `Images` column too.

I know that the booking information shouldn't belong to `Room` instead it should go to `Booking` table. I am thinking where should the booking time and checkout time go? in `Booking` table?

Comment: "should the **booking** time .. go .. in **Booking** table?"  I think when you read that back to yourself out loud you'll know what the answer is.

Comment: **Either** change Size to SizeSquareMetres and remove the units from the value **or** add a new column called SizeUnits and put the m^2 bit in there.

Answer (score 1):

Probably better to work with a metadata table. This, because the combination between different rooms and facilities can be quite hefty.

Have a look at this approach. I created an entity called <kbd>Establishment</kbd> so you can have Hotels, Hostels, B&B, etc under the same table, the difference comed from the type defined on your <kbd>EstablishmentType</kbd>. Specific details of addressing, for example, can be stored on another table that can be shared with the <kbd>Individuals</kbd> Entity (not represented in this example).

Anyway, [test schema](https://gist.github.com/errorware/9540511daecceb096fe7fd8ee912601c):

[image]

*Note that I choose to store the datatype on the Facilities table, this is probably discouraged because its associated with the concept of the [God Table](http://wiki.c2.com/?GodTable), if all you want to do is present a table with the room facilities (frontend-wise) just forget about it.*

This approach will allow you to have any number of facilities per room without crowding a single table with NULL values. The model allows, also, any number of Establishments and Rooms types. You could also add another table in between and give the option of separating rooms between different buildings, branches, etc.

Alternatively you could choose to store XML or JSON on the `RoomFacilities` and let the frontend do the magic and deserialize the content of that table.

```
{
    "facilities" : {
        "number" : "1"
        "beds" : "2",
        "tv" : "22inch",
        "size" : "20m^2"
        }
}
```

About the images: You should probably keep them stored on a file server and reference them from within and additional media table.

Comment: I liked the idea of storing JSON but if I in future I need to do some data analytics, will it be useful?